# I'm trying to fix my logo in the center of the navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBimL.png)
[Desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayRU4.png)

I am making a navbar and I want to fix my logo in the center of the navbar. I did it somehow but when I go to the mobile screen the logo is not exactly in the center and when I press my burger menu the logo moves to down.
How can I fix it please help me?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light sticky-top" style="background-color:transparent">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand neon" routerLink="/home">Shams Ali</a>
    <img class="img-fluid mr-auto logo" src="assets/logo.png"/>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto ">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link neon" routerLink="/home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link neon" routerLink="/project">Projetcs</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link neon" routerLink="/about">About Me</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link neon" routerLink="/contact">Contact Me</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

```
.logo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: calc((100% - 195px) / 2);
  z-index: 100000;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, you just have to set a top position :

**Css** :

```
.logo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: calc((100% - 195px) / 2);
  z-index: 100000;
  top: 15px;
}
```

**Fiddle**: https://www.codeply.com/p/5Cq8gytisY

Answer (score 0):

Try adding that to your styles:

```
.center {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```